# Are Nhibernate Helper Kits available for VS2008?

Tags: nhibernate, model-view-controller, helper

Can you provide some information on Nhibernate Helper Kits for VS2008 and which all are open source and which all are not. Can you also share some links that gives information on using NHibernate with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I think you mean to be asking about code generators.  You can find similar questions on StackOverflow already.  There are many options for NHibernate code generation.  What is it about the NHibernate Helper Kit that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by helper kits.

As far as using ASP.NET MVC with NHibernate [Jeffrey Palermo's blog](http://jeffreypalermo.com/) has a lot of good information on the topic. He goes into great depth in his book [ASP.Net MVC in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988622). Worth the read.

Comment: I mean there are tools which automatically generate the mapping files and the data access classes one of them is NHibernate Helper Kit. If you have any information on any such tool please share the information...Thanks